# Is there a word for an anniversary when you're not married?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Date-aversary? Or do you just say "We've been dating for X years?"

Comment: 2/10/2016. this poster's anniversary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anniversary just means a marking of some number of years - not necessarily of a marriage. So provided there is an agreed start date to when the relationship came into being or reached some critical level ("living together", perhaps), you can simply celebrate the anniversary of that date.

Comment: Those of us who've had cancer sometimes use "cancerversary" to describe dates at an integral number of years since diagnosis, or since initial treatment.